# The variable redeclared in the outermost block of a substatement

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  int b = 2;
  if(int a = 0){  // #condition
  }else if(b == 2){
    int a;  //#1
  }
}
```

The above code can be [compiled](https://godbolt.org/z/7r66oq) in both gcc and clang. However, according to what the relevant rules say, this code should be ill-formed.  The rules are:

[stmt.stmt#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.stmt#3)

> A name introduced by a declaration in a condition (either introduced by the decl-specifier-seq or the declarator of the condition) is in scope from its point of declaration until the end of the substatements controlled by the condition. If the name is redeclared in the **outermost block of a substatement controlled by the condition**, the declaration that redeclares the name is ill-formed.

Isn't the if-statement which follows the `else` not a substatement controlled by the condition? (i.e, only the condition at `#condition` executed to be `false` will the if-statement after `else` be executed). So, why a declaration that redeclares the name in the outermost block of such a substatement can be considered as a well-formed code?

Maybe there are some arguments for the phrase "substatement controlled by the condition" in that rules of version `n4659`, however, such an idea is obviously clear in the latest draft.

[stmt.stmt#stmt.pre-2](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.stmt#stmt.pre-2)

> A substatement of a statement is one of the following:
> for a selection-statement, **any of its statements** (but not its init-statement)

That means the statement after `else` is a substatement of the primary `if-statement`, then the next rules say that:
[stmt.stmt#stmt.pre-5](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.stmt#stmt.pre-5)

> A name introduced in a selection-statement or iteration-statement outside of any substatement is in scope from its point of declaration until the end of the statement's substatements. **Such a name cannot be redeclared in the outermost block of any of the substatements**

The rule obviously says that we cannot redeclared the same name as that declared in condition  in the outermost block of these substatements. So, I'm curious whether I have misunderstood these rules or there are some defectives in the draft?

Comment: Your example seems more complicated than needed. Aren't you asking why [this](https://godbolt.org/z/6839qG) compiles?

Comment: @cigien They're similar. So, yes. why the code in your link can be considered as a well-formed code?

Comment: I'm not saying it's well-formed necessarily. I was just trying to understand your question. I think [this](https://godbolt.org/z/YhEGcM) is what you're asking? I think it's something to do with the outermost block.

Comment: @M.M  Maybe. Another example is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/3Eoxra). IIUC, such a code should be ill-formed in the compilers which implement `n4659`. My meaning is that the statement after `case 1` is executed only the value of the condition  is `1`, so it should be considered as controlled by the condition. However, it should be well-formed in the latest  draft, because it's not the substatement of a `selection-statement`.

Comment: I don't think the *value* in the condition makes any difference. The same rules apply to all branches. It's the nested statements where there's a difference.

Comment: @jackX retracted my comment, I misread the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement in [stmt.stmt#stmt.pre-5](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.stmt#stmt.pre-5) explicitly says:

> [Note 2: A name introduced in a selection-statement or iteration-statement outside of any substatement is in scope from its point of declaration until the end of the statement's substatements. Such a name cannot be redeclared in the *outermost block* of any of the substatements ([basic.scope.block]). — end note]

The key term here is *outermost block* which is defined in [stmt.block#1](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.block#1):

> A compound statement (also known as a block) groups a sequence of statements into a single statement.
>
> > compound-statement:
> >
> > > { statement-seq opt }
>
> ...
>
> A compound statement defines a block scope.

So [stmt.stmt#stmt.pre-5](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.stmt#stmt.pre-5) is essentially saying:

```
if (int a = 0) 
{  // outermost block
  int a;  // so ill-formed  
}
```

but

```
if (int a = 0) 
{  // outermost block 
 {  // inner block
   int a;  // so well-formed 
 }  
}
```

The same rules apply in your example with the block introduced by the nested `if` statement.

Comment: I don't see any definition for `outermost block` in  stmt.block#1

Comment: Agreed. I can't find any usage of it that indicates it's a grammar term. This answer does rely on the English meaning of that. I'll see what I can find, but I suspect this may be all there is.

Comment: The standard most likely assumes at that point the reader if familiar enough with what a block scope is and presumes they are astute enough to be able to discern between levels and outer and inner. (even then it is far more clear than the C standards use of *effective type* in the strict aliasing rule...)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yeah, that's reasonable. A single sentence somewhere like "a `{}` introduces a nested block scope, within an outer block" would be nice. I don't know how exactly to phrase that anyway.

Comment: @cigien If understand the wording "outermost block" by English, why is `else if(...){}` not be considered as the `outermost block`(i.e, the `{` and `}` are in the outermost )?

Comment: <s>Pirate Code</s>C++ Standard *is more like "guidelines" as opposed to actually strict rules or laws...*

Comment: @jackX Because the rules change that to `else { if(...) {} }`.

Comment: @cigien  Is this "If the substatement in a selection-statement is a single statement and not a compound-statement, it is as if it was rewritten to be a compound-statement containing the original substatement."  that rule? So, the block scope defined by `original substatement` is not the outermost block, instead, the hypothesis `compound-statement`  after `else` is the outermost block ?

Comment: @jackX Correct. See the first code snippet in the answer. If those braces were not there, they would still be rewritten to a compound statement and create a new block.

Comment: @cigien So, how to interpret [this](https://godbolt.org/z/qM7o5a), there's no any rule says that there would be a hypothesis compound-statement add after the `case label `, if the statement following the `case label` is not a compound-statement.

Comment: @jackX The only example [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.stmt#stmt.select.general-2) is for an `if`, but my reading of it suggests that the compound statement is not *after* the `case` label, but includes it. i.e. `switch(a) { case 1: ; }` is rewritten to `switch(a) { { case 1: ; } }`.

Comment: @cigien which rule implies that? I couldn't find it out in the standard. IIUC,  `case label` is not the substatement of switch-statement.

Comment: @jackX The link I added in the comment. Like I said, there's no explicit example with a `switch`, but I think the rule covers that case as well.

Comment: @cigien I don't think the rule covers `case label` inside a switch, because `case label` is not a **substatement** of switch, which is defined [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.stmt#stmt.pre-2), the [rule](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.stmt#stmt.select.general-2) is totally about `substatement` of selection-statement

Comment: The rule about the `switch` (or `if`) itself introducing a new scope is separate. I actually can't seem to find the wording for that at the moment (though it's definitely the case)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings That's what I concerned here about the declaration in `case label`. So, how to interpret https://godbolt.org/z/1x5WMP

Comment: @jackX This is a tangent from your question. Please ask a new one (or perhaps discuss in chat)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings The new question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64709153/the-redeclaration-in-a-statement-after-case-label-inside-a-switch-statement)

Answer (score 3):

No.

You're missing the block scope introduced by the `else` substatement:

> [`[stmt.selected.general/2]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.stmt#stmt.select.general-2): The substatement in a *selection-statement* (each substatement, in the `else` form of the `if` statement) implicitly defines a block scope ([basic.scope]). If the substatement in a *selection-statement* is a single statement and not a compound-statement, it is as if it was rewritten to be a *compound-statement* containing the original substatement. *[..]*

i.e. your code is really:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int b = 2;
  if (int a = 0) {
  }
  else {
    if (b == 2) {
       int a;
    }
  }
}
```

Thus, the block you're looking at (the one introduced by the nested `if`) is not the "outermost" block in question. So, though `a` is in scope within that block, it can be shadowed.

This *does* mean [you can't declare an `a` inside a "naked" `else`](https://www.ideone.com/L9GEoB), i.e. the following is ill-formed:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int b = 2;
  if (int a = 0) {
  }
  else {
    int a;
  }
}

/*
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:9:9: error: redeclaration of ‘int a’
     int a;
         ^
prog.cpp:6:11: note: ‘int a’ previously declared here
   if (int a = 0) {
*/
```

Comment: I was just about to say that :-P

Comment: what's the definition of the wording "outermost block"?  why the implicitly defined block scope defined by the if-statement after `else` is not the "outermost block"?

Comment: @jackX Why would it be? It's not outermost. That's just an English word. The `else` has an implicit block, and it's the most outer block out of any block under the `else`. It's the outermost block. Furthermore, the nested `if` doesn't "implicitly define" anything...

Comment: The rule says,  "The substatement in a selection-statement (each substatement, in the else form of the if statement) implicitly defines a block scope", for the form of if constexpr <sub>opt</sub>( init-statement <sub>opt</sub> condition ) **statement** else **statement**, these statements that are emphasized all implicitly define a block scope, these's no rule in the standard says that `else` could generate a block scope.

Comment: @jackX This is the grammar construction for your conditional:  `if` `constexpr`ₒₚₜ `(` _init-statementₒₚₜ_ _condition_ `)` _statement_ `else` _statement_

Comment: @jackX That latter bit, the _statement_ after the `else`, is a "substatement" in this context. It has a block scope implicitly defined per the rule I quoted. That block scope is inherently the _outermost_ scope of that substatement (because what else would it be? that's what "outermost" means). So, that's the block scope affected by the redeclaration rule. Inside that, inside your nested `if` or whatever else introduces _another, more nested scope_ can shadow your variable `a` per all the usual scope rules. There's nothing weird or unusual here.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings  Is the key point in this sentence? that is "If the substatement in a selection-statement is a single statement and not a compound-statement, it is as if it was rewritten to be a compound-statement containing the original substatement." because the if-statement after `else` is not a `compound-statement` instead  a single statement, so the code `else if(...){}` could be rewritten as if it likes `else{ if(...){ // declaration }}`, so the `declaration` is not in the outermost block of the primary `if-statement`, Right?

Comment: @jackX Forget the if-statement after `else`, completely. It's irrelevant. Look at the first code block in my answer; everything between `else {` and `}` is a block scope. The outermost part of that is where you can't redeclare `a`. It's as simple as that.

Comment: All that language rule is saying, is "you can't redeclare stuff inside me without creating a new scope for it first", which is how _every_ scope works.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings  I said that  your  first code block in your answer is supported by "If the substatement in a selection-statement is a single statement and not a compound-statement, it is as if it was rewritten to be a compound-statement containing the original substatement.". In other words, `if constexpr( init-statement condition ) statement else statement`, if the statement after `else` is not a compound-statement, the form will be equivalent to `if constexpr( init-statement condition ) statement else {statement}`

Comment: @jackX I don't really have anything else to say.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings No offense.  How could you transform the form `int b = 2;
  if(int a = 0){  // #condition
  }else if(b == 2){
    int a;  //#1
  }` to the form `int b = 2;
  if (int a = 0) {
  }
  else {
    if (b == 2) {
       int a;
    }
  }`, which rule in the standard permit you do that?

Comment: @jackX Again, the one that I quoted. This is how `if`/`else` statements work in C++.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Do you refer to: If the substatement in a selection-statement is a **single statement and not a compound-statement**, it is as if **it was rewritten to be a compound-statement containing the original substatement**.?

Comment: @jackX: Yes.... that just means, `else X` becomes `else { X }`, but `else { X }` does not become `else { { X } }`. `{ X }` is a compound-statement; `X` is not. `{ if (Y) { ... } }` is a compound-statement; `if (Y) {...}` is not.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings  `but else { X } does not become else { { X } },` that's exactly. Because the rule only applies to the substatement of a selection-statement .  And  that's why you said the original substatement is placed in the outermost block `else{ original-substatement  }`, and the block scope defined by `original-substatement` is no more the outermost block, Right?

Comment: @jackX What...? _"Because the rule only applies to the substatement of a selection-statement"_ No, it's because the statement following `else` _is_ a substatement but it was already a compound-statement. You literally quoted that rule yourself, several times. Look, I'm going to bed... I suggest you spend some time thinking it over. Good luck!