# The redeclaration in a statement after case label inside a switch statement

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/a3Ez34)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    switch(int a  = 1){  //#condition
        case 1: switch(int a = 2){}
        case 2: switch(int a = 2){}
    }
}
```

why the redeclarations of `a` are well-formed in this example?
According to the following rule:

[basic.scope.block#3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.block#3)

> Names declared in the init-statement, the for-range-declaration, and in the condition of if, while, for, and switch statements are local to the if, while, for, or switch statement (including the controlled statement), and **shall not be redeclared** in a subsequent condition of that statement nor **in the outermost block (or, for the if statement, any of the outermost blocks) of the controlled statement**.

IIUC, both the declarations in  statement `switch(int a = 2){}` or `switch(int a = 2){}` are all in the outermost block of the **controlled statement** which is a compound-statement.

As contrast:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    switch(int a  = 1){  //#condition
        case 1: int a = 2;
    }
}
```

The redeclaration of `a` after `case 1` is ill-formed since it's redeclared in the outermost block of that statement.

### Clarify

According to [stmt.block](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.block), A block is an alias of a compound-statement. So the above rule totally says about **block**, it's regardless of scope. The rule is equivalent to:

> shall not be redeclared in the **outermost compound-statement** of the controlled statement.

So, what I can't understand here is that, since there's no any block between the condition of inner `switch` and the outermost block of the first `switch`, how could say that the condition of the inner `switch` is not in the outermost block of the outer `switch`?

```cpp
    switch(int a  = 1){  <-  outermost block of the primary `switch`
        case 1: switch(int a = 2 /*there's no any block contains this condition*/){}
    }
```

As contrast:

```cpp
    switch(int a  = 1){  <-  outermost block of the primary `switch`
        case 1: {  /* here exists a block between `int a = 2` and outermost block of the primary `switch`, so the condition definitely not in the outermost block*/
             switch(int a = 2 ){} 
        }
    }
```

Is there any rule in the standard that I have missed says about the transformation which is similar to [stmt.while#2](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.while#2), which will make the condition be contained in an invented block(compound-statement)?

Comment: The outermost block starts from `switch(int a  = 1){` ← this bracket. The `int a = 2` declaration is not in the outermost block.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer why, Isn't `int a = 2` not within `{` of `switch(int a  = 1)`?

Comment: It is in a new block that belongs to the inner `switch` statement.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm  which rule says that, please cite it here.

Comment: The one you've already cited. "local to the switch". The `int a = 2` is local to the inner switch.  It's the same scope nesting as `{ int b = 2; { int b = 3; } }`.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm  "local to the switch" is not clear, It does not mean the declaration in condition is in the block of that statement, A block has a terminology definition, which should be a [compound-statement](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.block).

Comment: Do you also believe that `switch (int a = 1) { case 1 : { int a; } }` should be illegal?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  That's irrelevant.  the second `a` is declared in a nested block  rather than in the outermost block of the switch statement. So, the example you cited does not violate the rule.  `switch (int a = 1) { case 1 :  int a;  }` should be ill-formed.

Comment: A nested block is **in** the outermost block. The nested switch statement is also **in** the outermost block. Both constitute a scope. If you think the scope is relevant, then both should be legal. If you think the scope is irrelevant, then both should be illegal. Otherwise, please find the wording in the standard that distinguishes between these two cases.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.scope.declarative#4, they're not in the same declarative region.

Comment: I'm not sure what how the quoted passage is relevant. I know what a declarative region is. I am asking you to explain why a name which is declared in a nested block and thus is local to a nested block is different from a name which is declared in a condition of a nested switch statement and thus is local to that switch statement. Why do you consider one a redeclaration and the other not? The quoted passage says nothing about that.

Comment: "there's no rule says that the init-statement or condition in switch statement will be placed in a new block created by that statement" I'm not sure why you want this to be "in a new block". The very statement that you quote says "Names declared in the init-statement, the for-range-declaration, and in the condition of if, while, for, and switch statements **are local to the if, while, for, or switch statement** (including the controlled statement). Similarly, names declared in a block are local to that block. There is no special rule that elevates blocks above other potential scopes.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Because there's no any rule in the standard says that the `switch statement` would create a new block where the condition or init-statement places. `are local to the if, while, for, or switch statement` is not clear.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  A block is a compound-statement. Something in the block means that something is in the compound-statement. Since there's no block created by `switch statement`, then such a `switch statement` is in the block where it appears, why the condition in that statement is not?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  The rule for [while](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.while#2) is very clear to know the condition is not in the block where the `while statement` appears, instead, the `condition` is in the block invented by the rule.

Comment: "switch statement would create a new block" I have no idea what this could ever mean. A block is a compound statement. A compound statement creates a scope. A switch statement is another kind of statement. It also creates a scope. Neither of the scopes is better ot worse or more privileged than the other.

Comment: "the condition is not in the block". I cannot find any difference between `while` and `switch` in this regard.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Please note the rule, it totally says that the relations between declaration and **block**(which should be a compound-statement), a `switch statement` is not a compound-statement, so it does not supply a block for `condition`. i.e, there's no intervening block between the condition and `outermost block`.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't follow you. You keep saying you need a block, and for the life of me I cannot understand why. Good luck anyway.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Sorry, I spent you some time.  I don't want to persist to need a `block`. Instead, the rule says that, namely "in the outermost block of the controlled statement." , where block is an alias of  compound-statement. The rule is regardless of scope(a scope appertains to `name`). anyhow, what I want to argue here is , if there's no any compound-statement between `condition` of the inner `switch` and the outermost block of the primary `switch`, how could say that `condition` is not in the outermost block where the condition appears? Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: It's a wording defect, move on, nothing to see here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real question is the meaning of **in** here.  Anything between the `{` and `}` that delimit the `switch` is of course *in* that “outermost block”, but the use of “outermost” clearly implies that we’re not supposed to consider portions of the program that are (also) inside a nested block.  The simplest way to reach that interpretation is to read “in” as “**directly** in”, in the same sense that “a function declared in a namespace” does not usually include member functions of classes in that namespace.  The *condition* of a nested `switch` is then exempt because declarations in it are not directly in any block.

[P1787R6](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r6.html), which was adopted in November 2020, clarifies the situation by rewriting [basic.scope.block] to specifically refer to the singular *scope* associated with the substatement, independently of transformations like that in [stmt.while]/2.

Comment: I'm not confused at meaning of `in`, as you said, `in` here shall be read as `directly in`. What I can't understand here is, where is the block of the declaration for a condition of the selection-statement? The rule [basic.scope.block#3] says that the position relation(redeclaration shall not in the block) between the redeclaration and the **block** ( which has a term definition, namely compound-statement). As you said in your answers, there's no rule that describes what the **block** of condition and init-statement is, only says what the scope their are.

Comment: So, think that rule in this way, because there's no any **block** between the outermost block and  the condition of the inside `switch`, hence, Does that mean the condition is literal in the outermost block(Anything between the `{ and }` ).

Comment: @jackX: Not being in any nested block does not mean that it’s directly in the outermost block—that would read “in the block and outside of any nested block” or “whose innermost enclosing block is the block”.

Comment: So that's vague here. Neither existing a rule says that where's the block of the condition nor existing a rule specifically says that the block of the condition is where the `statement` appears. Furthermore, the rule that describes about the condition(or init-statement) in a statement only talks about its scope, however, for a declaration, it always has a **delcarative region**, such as blocks(compound-statements). I don't know that for the declaration for  condition in `switch`. The whole standard seems to say nothing about that.

Comment: Presumably, the essense for the rule says that there can't be two declarations with the same **name** in a single **declarative region** 
 (https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.declarative#4). However, I don't know which  kind of `declarative region` the condition in `switch` declared in (block? you said that it's not in any block, this is weird), furthermore the parameter of a function. I really really hope to know that. Unfortunately, I can't find any rule talks about that in the standard.

Comment: @jackX: It sounds a bit self-serving, but I would recommend reading P1787; it was written for a reason!

Comment: Could you give a index in P1787 that would clear these confusions (include which and where declarative region they are), thanks.

Comment: @jackX: It’s [basic.scope.block], like I said in the answer, plus some minor simplifications throughout [stmt].  And everything in that paper is based on the terminology introduced in the new [basic.scope.scope] that replaces [basic.scope.declarative].

Answer (score 0):

There's no such rule. The code in [stmt.while/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.stmt#stmt.while-2) is misleadingly redundant; it could equally be written

```
label:
if ( condition ) {
    statement
    goto label ;
}
```

It is necessary to look at the meaning of the word "in" in [stmt.pre/5](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.pre#5) and [basic.scope.block/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.block#3):

> Names declared in the init-statement, the for-range-declaration, and in the condition of if, while, for, and switch statements are local to the if, while, for, or switch statement (including the controlled statement), and shall not be redeclared in a subsequent condition of that statement nor in the outermost block (or, for the if statement, any of the outermost blocks) of the controlled statement.

Here, "in" means "immediately in"; it's referring to declaration-statements which would have scope the remainder of the block. Declarations via the condition of a selection statement are not "in" the enclosing block, they are "in" that selection statement.

Comment: I can understand the **scope** of the declaration for the condition shall be local to that selection statement, however the rule about the redeclaration says the relation between such a redeclaration and a block which has a term definition, namely **compound-statement**. that's the confusion,  selection statements do not supply a block for the condition to divide it with the outer block.  In other words, the rule only says that these  statements can divide a new scope for the condition, the init-statement but not a new block.

Comment: @jackX they don't need to; a (re)declaration in the condition of a selection statement is not a redeclaration in the enclosing block.

Comment: @jackX the "outermost block" is just a way of referring to the relevant scope.

Comment: where's the rule indicates that "a (re)declaration in the condition of a selection statement is not a redeclaration in the enclosing block."?  I have to say, there's indeed a term definition for wording "block", which is compound-statement, see "A compound statement (also known as a block) ", suppose a block is a box,  and the outermost block is Box A, there is not a  box B  in the box A that contains the condition(means cut off from A), why you say that the condition is not in box A? Since you say the rule is referring to scope, why does not the rule use the wording "outermost block scope"?

Comment: @jackX there doesn't need to be such a rule; if there are two possible readings of a document (a declaration in the condition is/is not a declaration in the enclosing block) then you choose the reading that makes most sense and reflects existing practice. The Standard is a *legal* document, not a *formal* specification. You seem to have decided that the word *in* is delimited by block scopes; where is your justification for this reading?

Comment: If there's no defective in this rule, why would [P1787](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p1787r5.html) completely change that.